# To get JSON file values on a label on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to get values from a json file (text file) into a label depending on the input given in textbox on button click.

this is for autocomplete textbox request but first I am trying to fetch values on label.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="hint1"></span></p>

    <input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="loadVal()" />

    <button type="button" onclick="loadVal()">Click</button>
    <script>
      function loadVal() {
        try {
          var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
              alert("inside function");
              var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
              obj = JSON.parse(obj);
              if (obj[0].sl_no == str) {
                for (i in obj.sl_no) {
                  document.getElementById("hint1").innerHTML = obj[i].sl_no;
                }
              }
            }

            xhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();
          };
        } catch (err) {
          alert(err.message);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</form>
```

JSON text file contains:

```
 "[{\"sl_no\":\"305\"},{\"sl_no\":\"305\"},{\"sl_no\":\"3056\"},
{\"sl_no\":\"3057\"},{\"sl_no\":\"3305\"}]"
```

expected output is 305, 3056, 3057, 3305

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Nothing is happening on button_click. i checked with alert box inside xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() and alert is also not coming.

Comment: Don't mixup the `js` and `html code`. You have added the `js code` within the `form` tag. Does your function `loadVal()` gets invoked?

Comment: Function loadVal() is not working properly. I mean an alert box before xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() is working but after that the function is not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggestions:

Click

```
<script>

        function loadVal()
        {
            try
            {                    
                var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
                xhttp.send();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {

                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        obj = JSON.parse(obj);
                        if (obj[0].sl_no == str) 
                        {
                            for (i = 1; i < obj.length; i++)
                            {

                                document.getElementById("hint1").innerHTML += obj[i].sl_no + " ";
                            }  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```js
const input = [{"sl_no":"305"},{"sl_no":"305"},{"sl_no":"3056"},{"sl_no":"3057"},{"sl_no":"3305"}];


function loadVal() {
  try {
    var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    const filteredOutput = input.filter((obj) => {
      const val = Object.values(obj)[0];
      return val.startsWith(str);
    });
    console.log(filteredOutput);
  } catch (err) {}
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="hint1"></span></p>
    <input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="loadVal()" />
    <button type="button" onclick="loadVal()">Click</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON not in the correct format that's why an error occurs, before parse we make it VALID JSON format.

```
<html>
<body>
<script >
function loadVal() {
        try {
          var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
          xhttp.send();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
              var obj='{ "hint":'+this.responseText.substring(1, this.responseText.length-1).replace(/\\/g,"")+'}'
              var obj = JSON.parse(obj);

              if (obj.hint[0].sl_no == str) {
                for (i in obj.hint) {
                  document.getElementById("hint1").innerHTML = obj.hint[i].sl_no;
                }
              }
            }


          };
        } catch (err) {
          alert(err.message);
        }
      }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="hint1"></span></p>

    <input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="loadVal()" />

    <button type="button" onclick="loadVal()">Click</button>

  </div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```